# Issue in preview , Jetpack Compose Android

Tags: android, api, android-jetpack-compose

A lot of errors showing on API ,

Showing Error in LazyVerticalGrid section :

```
This foundation API is experimental and is likely to change or be removed in the future.
```

In weekdays section :

```
Field requires API level 26 (current min is 21): `java.time.DayOfWeek#SUNDAY`
```

In months section there is this error:

```
Field requires API level 26 (current min is 21): `java.time.Month#JULY`
```

This is my code below .

```
package com.example.android.weatherapp.ui.components

import android.os.Build
import androidx.annotation.DrawableRes
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.compose.foundation.ExperimentalFoundationApi
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.GridCells
import com.example.android.weatherapp.R
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.GridItemSpan
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyVerticalGrid
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.items
import androidx.compose.material.Card
import androidx.compose.material.Icon
import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextAlign
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import com.example.android.weatherapp.ui.theme.WeatherAppTheme
import java.time.DayOfWeek
import java.time.format.TextStyle
import java.util.*

data class Month(
    val title : String ,
    val dateForecasts: List<DateForeCast>
)

data class DateForeCast(
    val date: String,
    val highTemperature: String,
    @DrawableRes val icon: Int
)
@Composable
fun Calendar(
    months : List<Month>,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
){
    val gridCellNumber = 7
    LazyVerticalGrid(
        modifier = modifier ,
        cells = GridCells.Fixed(gridCellNumber)
    ){
        months.forEach { month ->
            item(
                span = { GridItemSpan(gridCellNumber) }
            ) { MonthLabel(month = month.title) }
            items(month.dateForecasts){
                DateCard(dataForecasts = it )
            }
        }
    }
}
@Composable
fun MonthLabel(
    month: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
){
    val weekdays = listOf(
            DayOfWeek.SUNDAY,
            DayOfWeek.MONDAY,
            DayOfWeek.TUESDAY,
            DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY,
            DayOfWeek.THURSDAY,
            DayOfWeek.FRIDAY,
            DayOfWeek.SATURDAY
        ).map{
            it.getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, Locale.getDefault())
        }

    Column(
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        Text(
            text = month ,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.h5.copy(fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold)
        )
        Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth() ){
            weekdays.forEach{
                Text(
                    text = it,
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2,
                    modifier = Modifier.weight(1f,true)
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
@Preview(
    showBackground = true
)
@Composable
fun CalendarPreview(){
    val months = listOf(
        Month(
            title = "July",
            dateForecasts = List(java.time.Month.JULY.length(false)){
                DateForeCast(
                    date = "$it + 1",
                    highTemperature = "70",
                    icon = R.drawable.cloud_cloudy_day_forecast_sun_icon
                )
            }
        ),
        Month(
            title = "August",
            dateForecasts = List(java.time.Month.AUGUST.length(false)){
                DateForeCast(
                    date = "$it + 1",
                    highTemperature = "70",
                    icon = R.drawable.cloud_cloudy_day_forecast_sun_icon
                )
            }
        )

    )
    WeatherAppTheme {
        Calendar(months = months )
    }
}
@Composable
fun DateCard(
    dataForecasts: DateForeCast,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) = Card (
    modifier = modifier,
){
    Column (
        modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ){
        Text(
            text = dataForecasts.date,
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.overline,
            color = Color.Blue
        )
        Icon(
            painter = painterResource(id = dataForecasts.icon ),
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(vertical = 16.dp)
                .size(24.dp),
            tint = Color.Unspecified
        )
    }
}
```

This is mainly the issue of SDK, but still its not working properly.
I tried the inbuild suggestions to remove the error but it's still no progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the solution for this.

You just have to change your **compileSDK** and **targetSDK** to **33** in **gradle build**.
Then just clear the cache and your build will work properly .